# Laravel Eloquent Query WITH parameters

Tags: laravel, dynamic, eloquent, with-statement, eloquent-relationship

Morning,

il would like to use Eloquent to make this request but i have an error.

```
$ModelVars=Model1::with(['Model2' => function($query,$var){
                            return $query->where('field1', 'like', '%'.$var.'%');}])->get();
```

Could somebody help me.
Thks in advance.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Tks @Jackowski, See below error :   Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Achat\DemandeachatsController::App\Http\Controllers\Achat\{closure}(), 1 passed in ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php on line 431 and exactly 2 expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to :

```
$ModelVars = Model1::with(['Model2' => function($query) use ($var){
    return $query->where('field1', 'like', '%'.$var.'%'); }])
->get();
```

`use` is not a function, it's part of the [Closure syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) It simply makes the specified variables of the outer scope available inside the closure.